# How to copy/export default android browser browsing history to android chrome?

Tags: stock-browser, samsung-galaxy-j5, browser-history

how's it going?
I have been using android default browser of galaxy j5 for about 1 year and it doesn't show browsing history beyond like 3 months (only last 3 months or less) and my browsing history is so precious to me. 
How can I move/copy all this browsing history to android google chrome, or even desktop chrome.
And after all, what's the best way to save them for good, like in my computer?.
Much appreciated.
So eager to hear a sooner response.

Comment: Search history means?

Comment: All pages and websites I visited=History (stock browser)

Comment: You mean to say browsing history.

Comment: Yes!....sorry I mistyped it due to excitement!

Comment: Well AFAIK, chrome for android doesn't support importing of history (I'm not even sure if desktop version support that). And I'm pretty sure you can't export history from stock bowser. You can switch to chrome but you will not have history, however you can stay with stock browser and when you stumble upon page you thing you may need, simply bookmark it. P.s. you can't export/import bookmarks with chrome, not sure about other browsers.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. The big problem is that I can't see history older than 1 month which I really need. Besides can't I make stock browser browsing history a HTML file and transfer it to computer chrome? if so, how?  Једноруки Крстивоје